# CSS Flex: Two columns with fixed width and remaining two columns with relative wdith

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I have a four column table, I want columns 3 and 4 to have a fixed width of 200 px and col1 and col2 to share 50% each of the remaining width.

I am trying something like this, but not getting the desired results. Can someone help?

https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-architecture-lw1t6?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: change the `width: 200px` as `min-width: 200px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you.

```
.col3, .col4 {
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

this is a revision ( and rule `max-width` has no `auto` parameter ):

```
.col1,
.col2 {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 0;
}

.col3,
.col4 {
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but the width for col1 and col2 is not coming equal (there is a difference of some 20 px).

When I do 
`
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 200px 200px;
`

It works just fine, but we are not willing to use grid layout due to compatabilityissues.

Comment: I once again looked at your css code, and did not see the grid post. If you use your code that you provided and my solution, then you get the result you want. I checked again.

Comment: I understood why it was working fine in the sandbox and not in my actual implementation. I have changed the sandbox to give you a better understanding of what is happening. Could you please check - https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-morning-kj5xu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `auto` is not a valid value for `max-width`. ok, now I'll see an example

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use max-width CSS property in that particular box in which you want to apply the fixed size.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>FLEX</title>
    <style type="text/css">
 body{
 font-size: 20px;
 }
 h1{
 font-size: 24px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 }
 .parent{
 display: flex;
 
 text-align: center;
 }
 .parent > * {
 padding: 20px;
 flex: 1 100%;
  }
 .child-1{
    max-width: 200px; //max width
 background: blue;
 }
 .child-2{
 background: green;
 max-width: 200px;  //max width
 }
 .child-3{
 background: yellow;
 }
 .child-4{
 background: pink;
 }


 }

 }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>FLex box with 2 fixed box</h1>
 <div class="parent">
 <div class="child child-1"><strong>Child 2</strong><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 </div>
 <div class="child child-2">Child 3 <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</div>

 <div class="child child-3"><strong>Child 4</strong><br> Lorem ipsum
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
 <div class="child child-4">Child 5 <br> Lorem ipsum
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

set min-width:200px; ,max-width:auto; for which you want to set fixed 200px size and for other column you can give set width in percentage.
You can **inspect** and play around the code.